# Does "My Portfolio" update live on GTA V?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v, ps4

I am currently investing lots of money in the LCN stock market. If I click on the "My Portfolio" tab and leave it on this screen does the "Return Percentage" update/refresh live as the stocks rise and fall, or do I have to back out of the window and then go back into "My Portfolio" section to see any updates in my share returns?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

It does update live-ish on BAWSAQ and live on LCN.
On BAWSAQ, as soon as it downloads prices online, it updates, even if you don't refresh the page.
On LSC, it always updates even if you don't refresh the page.